# Calculate distance of a roadway segment

Tags: javascript, maps, mapbox, postgis

I want to calculate the distance of a roadway segment. I have the segment data as polygon. How to do this with javascript?

Example segment image
[image]

I know the distance calculation between two points is possible using the `geolib` npm module. But I want to calculate the distance of the segment polygon.

```
geolib.getDistance(
    {latitude: 38.837409, longitude: -106.147765},
    {latitude: 38.840000, longitude: -106.138806}
);
```

**Update:**

Got `ST_MaxDistance` function in PostGIS to calculate the distance in projected degrees. Is there a way to get the distance in meters from `ST_MaxDistance`function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty simple.
Just follow the steps below:

1. Push all the distance points into an array in correct order.
2. Iterate them one by one to get the distance between two dots and sum them up.

The code is as below:

```
let result = 0
let points = []

// These points are for example
points.push({ latitude:0, longitude:0 }, { latitude: 3, longitude: 4}, {latitude: 15, longitude: 9})


for (let i=0; i<points.length-1; i++) {
    result += geolib.getDistance(points[i], points[i+1])
}

console.log(result) // result should be 18 in this case
```

It should solve your issue, try this out.

Comment: Do I need to give all the polygon points in this approach? Also Is there any API available in google maps to achieve this?

Comment: Usually, google map only provide ways to interact with map items, I think you should write the logics using javascript on your own.

Comment: And yes, you should take all the points in your path in to an array, in order to calculate the distance between each two dots and sum them up.

Comment: Ok @Arel I think your solution will bring the distance of the whole polyline which will be more than doubler length of the distance. I want the distance from the start of the segment to end.

Comment: I think not, have you try it yet? It calculates the length from start to end.

Comment: I haven't tried yet. Will try and let you know. Thanks for the help

Comment: No problem. It won't calculate twice because you can only get one distance out of two points.